# Reference for Derivation of Higher order Runge Kutta

Tags: reference-request, runge-kutta-methods

I have a problem about determining $a_1, a_2, k_1, k_2, \ldots a_n, k_n,\ldots$

In the general form of the Higher Order Runge-Kutta below :

$$y_{r+1}=y_r+a_1k_1+a_2k_2+\cdots+a_nk_n$$

For the convenient, i'll write it down The Runge Kutta $2^{\text{nd}}$ in my book just in case if the formula is different from your views:

$$
\begin{align}
k_1&=hf(x_r,y_r)\\
k_2&=hf(x_r+p_1h,y_r+q_{11}k_1)\\ 
y_{r+1}&=y_r+(a_1k_1+a_2k_2)
\end{align}
$$

I'm not really sure, but some sources talk about Butcher Tableau, slope for each $k_n$, Taylor expansion, and rooted trees, for determining the $a_n$. And i don't really understand what their relation is, especially for Butcher Tableau, and rooted trees.

Could you explain all of these for me? Or just give me a good reference that discusses about derivation of the higher order Runge-Kutta method in detail, please?

Because, some books just skip over the derivation part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source on Butcher tableaus and B-trees would, almost canonically, be the book by Butcher himself. For a short overview, see the [three sets of slides](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/) with an introduction to B-trees, demonstration of the method for up to order 4 and outlook to implicit methods, or a [historical overview](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~asandu/Public/Qual2011/DiffEqn/Butcher_1996_RK-history.pdf)

You could of course also read the most original source, the introduction of Runge-Kutta methods by M. Wilhelm Kutta (1901), [*"Beitrag zur näherungsweisen Lösung totaler Differentialgleichungen"*](https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog/page/n449), where the order conditions are established and solved up to order 4, with an order 5 method that turned out not to be correct for systems.

Comment: Is this source containing how to derive the RK formula?